# Ruby on Rails. Increase integer in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables

I have created a website using Ruby on rails and have a database with points for my users.
Every user has points so I would refer to it as `@user.points`.
I am able to view the points by using:

```
<%= user.points %>
```

I am trying to increase these points from my page as users complete a certain action. So I tried doing:

```
<% @user.points += 100 %>
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I feel there is a simple solution or I am overseeing something.

Comment: There have been some good answers, but you definately don't want to do this in your view, you are better off running it in your controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`increment(attribute, by = 1)`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment):

> Initializes attribute to zero if nil and adds the value passed as by
>   (default is 1). The increment is performed directly on the underlying
>   attribute, no setter is invoked. Only makes sense for **number-based**
>   attributes. Returns self.

```
@user.increment(:points,  100)
```

Example:

```
 => user = User.last
 => user.points
 =# 100
 => user.increment(:points, 100)
 => user.points
 =# 200
 => user.increment(:points, 100)
 => user.points
 =# 300
 =# ......
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the value when a user is doing a certain action, then you should update points in the controller when the given action is triggered.

```
Class MyController
  def given_action
    @user.update_attributes(points: new_value)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a member action to perform the increment task

```
def increase_points
  user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
  user.update_attributes(points: (user.points + 100))
end
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add an exlamation mark to Зелёный's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36006157/1417223) and the object gets updated directly as well:

```
user.increment!(:points, 1)
```